# how can I fix text centering at the end of a figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, minipage, text

I have this situation :

[image]

I don't know how to left-align the text.
I don't want to use flushleft and noindent doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Luca

```
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{minipage}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{Output Link (4)}
  \resizebox{6.5cm}{6.2cm}{
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  ...
  ...
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{align} \label{eq:sis3}
  \begin{cases}
  F_{34_{(x)}} + F_{14_{(x)}} \ = \  ma_{D_{(x)}}\\
  F_{34_{(y)}} + F_{14_{(y)}} - F_{p} \ = \  ma_{D_{(y)}}\\
  F_{34_{(y)}}r_2\cos{(\theta_4)} - F_{34_{(x)}}r_2\sin{(\theta_4)} \ = \ I_4\alpha_4
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}

  text...
```

And the text become like it was centered....

Comment: Can you make a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` demonstrating the problem? If I put your snippet into a file and add the necessary bits `text ...` is *not* centered.  Another thing: `H` is not a valid option for `minipage`, you can choose between `t`, `c` (default) and `b`.

Comment: ah ok. I just realized I forgot a \begin{figure} before a \begin{tikzpicture} so it made a mess. Now it is correctly left-align. Thanks a lot !!